# How to obtain second and fourth word from each line in a file

Tags: python

**Example**: File will be called "**`Sentences.dat`**". It will have these lines.

> Name #3 is Bob
>
> Name #7 is Marie
>
> Name #8 is Kate
>
> Name #2 is George

I want to save these to a **`dictionary`**, where their number is the `key` and their name is the `value`. This is what I have so far.

```
file = open("Sentences.dat","r")
dictNames = {}
line = 1
while True:
    content = file.readlines()[line]
    split = content.split()
    dictNames[split[1]] = split[3]
    line = line + 1
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Where's the `break` statement in `loop`?

Comment: Initialize **line** as `0` since indexing begins with `0` in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another efficient way to do that..

```
dictNames = {}
with open('Sentences.dat', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        dictNames[words[1]] = words[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dictNames = {}
with open("Sentences.dat") as file:
    for line in file:
        parts = line.split()
        num = int(parts.lstrip('#'))
        dictNames[num] = parts[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I also left some comments in the code.

```
import io  # just for testing
from operator import itemgetter


# just for testing
file_content = """Name #3 is Bob

Name #7 is Marie

Name #8 is Kate

Name #2 is George
"""

# replace io.StringIO with open("Sentences.dat","r")
file = io.StringIO(file_content)  # just for testing

names = dict()

ig = itemgetter(1, 3)
with file:  # make sure file is closed after parsing using with
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        # skip empty lines
        if not line:  
            continue
        # itemgetter is optional but fast and worth knowing
        hash_number, name = ig(line.split())
        number = int(hash_number[1:])
        names[number] = name

print(names)  # just for testing
```

Result: {3: 'Bob', 7: 'Marie', 8: 'Kate', 2: 'George'}

Comment: The accepted answer will break on empty lines that are in the example data and numbers are stored as strings. I still think my answer could be helpful for the poster.